# Do I need an App ID to query the feed of a public profile on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

We are trying to build a custom list of recent posts on a customer's Facebook page using the Javascript library of the Graph API. Doing something like `http://graph.facebook.com/idea.int.SoD/picture` works fine, but I understand that I need to authenticate for `http://graph.facebook.com/idea.int.SoD?fields=posts.limit(5)` amongst others.

I have registered a new App on the Facebook admin interface, and am trying to init and login with Javascript like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
      appId: '...',
      xfbml: true, // if true parse your page's DOM to find and initialize any social plugins that have been added using XFBML
      status: true, // the SDK will attempt to get info about the current user immediately after init
      version: 'v2.1'
    });

    FB.login(
      function (response) {
        console.log("Response form FB.login", response);
      },
      {
        // scope: 'publish_actions' // get permission in order to make publishing API calls
        scope: 'manage_pages' // manipulate a FB page (not a user)
      }
    );

  FB.api(
     "/idea.int.SoD?fields=posts.limit(5)",
     function (response) {
          ...
```

But I get `"type": "OAuthException", "code": 104` as a response.

My question is:

How do we get this AppID authorized by the customer's profile so that it can make these calls. Do I need to go through the whole app publishing process just to create a custom widget on their website?

And can this work independently of the user visiting the site? i.e. that it's the App looking up this data from the feed, rather than the visitor logging in and doing the API request.

Comment: that´s a very bad js login code...take a look at this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Thanks for the link, however for my purposes I'm not sure I really need to login at all since I just want to look up the last 5 public posts for this `idea.int.SoD` account and show them in a custom way. It really should require a visitor to have a Facebook account at all...